# Android Dialog dialog (activity context) not dismissed when activity is killed in background

Tags: android, memory-leaks, dialog, kill, dismiss

This one is fairly simple, so I hope I get an answer
I have an Activity which displays dialogs using both fragments (dismiss is easy to handle in fragment) and the classic `Dialog dialog (Context c)` where context is the activity context I get in `onCreate()` using `mContext = this`

Now, if I activate the developer's option to kill all activities in background, whenever I hit the home button while the dialog is displayed, the dialog is never dismissed and I get a Memory Leak error in Android Studio log cat.

To create the dialog in main activity:

```
private Dialog mDialog = null; // I want to get rid of these references
private void showDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, mParams.applicationTheme);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.common_dialog);
    mDialog = dialog;

    // set title and text message of dialog
    // set button_ok and button_cancel from resources

    button_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // do some stuff
            dialog.dismiss();
            mDialog = null;
        }
    });

    button_cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            mDialog = null;
        }
    });

    dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            button_cancel.performClick();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

```
private Context mContext;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContext = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

The only way to avoid memory leak error in Android Studio when activity is killed in background is to keep a reference to the dialog and dismiss it in onDestroy():

```
onDestroy() {
    if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing())
        mDialog.dismiss();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I thought that the Dialogs created with activity context are destroyed when the activity is destroyed, but this is not the case when the activity is killed in background, unless I am implementing it wrong.

Is there a simpler way than having to hold a reference of every single dialog ?

Notice: I properly handle the dialogs state in `onConfigurationChanged()` and I don't need to handle the dialogs when activity is killed in these dialogs

Comment: "and causes a memory leak when it is recreated by the system" -- Android does not recreate dialogs automatically (you need to use `DialogFragment` for that). "this is not the case when the activity is killed in background" -- it is possible that this is not the case when you have that developer option enabled. Personally, I never use that option, as it bears no resemblance towards anything that actually happens in the real world. "unless I am implementing it wrong" -- your [mcve] does not show much of your code, and what is there will not compile. FWIW, I generally use a `DialogFragment`.

Comment: @CommonsWare : I added more code details in my original question. I enabled that option to simulate the app behavior when it would be killed because of low memory for example. I don't need to restore it from a bundle in that case, but I don't want it to leak !

Comment: "I enabled that option to simulate the app behavior when it would be killed because of low memory for example" -- [Android does not destroy activities for low memory -- it kills processes](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare : thank you a lot, I was not aware of that. So, what is the recommended approach that is generally admitted ? Leave leaking dialogs and fragments for this edge case, or create a reference for all dialogs and ensure to dismiss them in onDestroy ? Surely using a common dialog fragment would be a better idea as we can dismiss the single fragment in its own onDestroy(). I would just need to migrate all my old Dialogs...

Comment: "So, what is the recommended approach that is generally admitted ?" -- recommended approach for *what*? "Leave leaking dialogs and fragments for this edge case, or create a reference for all dialogs and ensure to dismiss them in onDestroy ?" -- have you reproduced your problem using anything other than a "developer options" hack?

Comment: @CommonsWare No, the problem only occurs when the "Developer option" is enabled. All other situations are properly handled (screen rotation, app sent to background) when that developer option is disabled. Should I be concerned about that edge case when using Dialog ? Thank you again for teh followup: If you post it as answer, I will accept it as the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem only occurs when the "Developer option" is enabled

In that case, I would not worry about it. Developer options like that do unnatural things that will not happen to ordinary users.

Personally, I use a `DialogFragment` rather than a bare `Dialog`, but otherwise I see nothing out of the ordinary with your code other than your use of `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`, which should not result in a real-world memory leak.